# Function parameter of char* type in dynamically linked library (dll/so)

Tags: c++, c, opengl, linker

I compiled a vendor specific OpenGL header meant to be compiled with a hardware specific static library, but I linked and ran with an nVidia Quadro 4000 card and library (linux). This is how our vendor says we should do it in host environment so it should be no worries.

I found something odd though. The vendor specific headers had GLchar typedeffed as an 'unsigned char' (sigh...) while the nVidia header typedeffed it a 'char'. Those types are not the same but it still "works". I can´t implicitly cast char* to unsigned char*, that gives me a compile error, but I can link AND successfully run functions (glGetUniformLocation) library probably built using 'char' prototypes.

What happened? Did the runtime resolve it by deciding 'char' is "close-enough" to 'unsigned char'? Or are occurances of 'char' expanded to one signedness or the other when building the library? If so, what would happen if I overload a function with all three kinds of signedness?

Edit: Note the OpenGL library use C-linkage which explains my particular experience as described in accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use C linkage, functions are linked by their literal name. Unlike C++ with its name mangling, nothing controls types of arguments. When your program calls function, it put arguments on stack or in registers (according to calling convention) and function reads it. Pointer is put (4 or 8 bytes), pointer is read (of same size). Caller interprets pointer as `unsigned char*`, callee interprets it as `char*`.

If callee read more or less bytes than caller put, stack will be corrupted that will lead to strange, unwanted behavior.

If callee read `int` after caller put `float`, callee will process garbage rather than sensible data.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot the OpenGL library is using c linkage.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, that's good that you understand what's going on. I already added couple of notes which are probably obvious for you.